# How to run Saxon on an XQuery Update file from the command line?

Tags: xquery, saxon, xquery-update

This page [1] on the Saxon web site says:

> Update is available only in Saxon-EE, and is supported only if
> explicitly requested. The command line has an option -update:on for
> this purpose ...

and

> Note that updates to a document will fail unless it is implemented
> using the Linked Tree model. This can be selected from the command
> line using -tree:linked ...

So, I added those options and invoked Saxon from the command line:

```
java -classpath %CLASSPATH% net.sf.saxon.Transform -update:on -tree:linked example.xml -xsl:example.xsl -o:out.xml
```

When I executed that, I got this error message:

```
Command line option -update is not recognized.
```

What is the right way to invoke Saxon for XQuery Update?

[1] https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/using-xquery/update.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `net.sf.saxon.Query`, not Transform. And `-s:input.xml query.xq`.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Honnen This seems to work: java -classpath %CLASSPATH% net.sf.saxon.Query -update:on -tree:linked -q:example.xq

Comment: @RogerCostello, someone wrote a tutorial explaining that at https://www.xfront.com/xquery/ some while ago :).